# Catching EM_SETCHARFORMAT and modifying the CHARFORMAT data in EN_PROTECTED

Tags: mfc, winapi

I am receiving a EM_CHARFORMAT message in my message handler when SetFont() is called on my custom control. But when I change the data in the CHARFORMAT structure pointed to in the LPARAM, it isn't being used.

```
void CMyRichEdit::OnProtected(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    ENPROTECTED* pEP = (ENPROTECTED*)pNMHDR;
    *pResult = 1; 

    switch(pEP->msg)
    {
    case EM_SETCHARFORMAT:
        {
        CHARFORMAT *cf = reinterpret_cast<CHARFORMAT *>(pEP->lParam);
        cf->dwEffects |= (CFE_PROTECTED | CFE_ITALIC); 
        cf->dwMask |= (CFM_PROTECTED | CFM_ITALIC);
        *pResult = 0; 
        }
        break;
```

The MSDN docs say only if the lParam value changes is it used over the original... but here lParam is a pointer to an object. How can I allocate a new object without the memory leaking?

Comment: I can't make sense of this code.  Why is NMHDR there?  Why are you setting pResult?  The message needs to be processed by the default window procedure to make your changes effective.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This is working code. Hacking about the default window proc is a last resort. Read up on EN_PROTECTED, CRichEditCtrl::SetEventMask(), and ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I allocate a new object without the memory leaking?

I'm not sure that reallocating lParam is going to work, but since a window procedure doesn't have to worry about being called on multiple threads, you can point lParam to a static variable safely.  That way you don't have to worry about freeing it.

```
case EM_SETCHARFORMAT:
    {
    static CHARFORMAT mycf;
    CHARFORMAT *cf = reinterpret_cast<CHARFORMAT *>(pEP->lParam);
    mycf = *cf;
    pEP->lParam = (LPARAM)(LONG_PTR)&mycf;
    cf->dwEffects |= (CFE_PROTECTED | CFE_ITALIC); 
    cf->dwMask |= (CFM_PROTECTED | CFM_ITALIC);
    *pResult = 0; 
    }
    break;
```

However, I really don't think that this is going to solve your problem.